# Why does "nautilus"(Gnome FIles) gives me so smaller size of directory, compared with "du"?

Tags: filesystems, disk-space, nautilus, du

I have compressed a folder and if I right click in the folder and click properties, I get from nautilus (Gnome Files)

[image: Gnome Files output]

but instead if I run du (from the `branches` parent directory):

```
$ du -sh *
292M    branches
236M    branches.zip
```

so why the folder has SO DIFFERENT size output between the two programs?

other infos:
inside `branches`, there are other folders. I have a BTRFS. 4096 of block size.

Comment: Inspecting the contents of this folder, is the 75MB that Nautilus reports possibly accounted for in the contents only of the first level of the folder, and subfolders are not accounted for? Can you give us more details on the contents of this folder?

Comment: @music2myear inside `branches` folder there are ONLY other folders, so no single files

Comment: @DrMoishePippik in the first level, as I wrote, there are ONLY folders

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504267/why-does-nautilusgnome-files-gives-me-so-smaller-size-of-directory-compared

Comment: It's likely you'll get better answers over there, but please note that cross posting isn't appreciated on this group of sites. For certain sites you can request a question be moved, but if that isn't possible you should close/delete the one question and post it to the new site rather than leaving both up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been crossposted to AskUbuntu and appears to be getting better answers over there.